# Could new users be prompted to edit instead of commenting?

Tags: feature-request, comments, edits

It's very common to ask for additional information on a question.  This is perhaps most common with new users who are a little unfamiliar with the need to put all relevant information in their question to start with.

To be blunt, I'm a little tired of explaining to new users that an edit is better than a comment, particularly where we ask *"please add the output of..."* I note that some users have taken to explicitly asking OPs to edit their question and adding an edit link in their comment.  But still this is missed.

More recently, adding a comment to a new user's question displays a little note saying:

> ... is a new contributor. Be nice, and check out our Code of Conduct.

Could there be a similarly formatted note to new contributors commenting on their own question or answer:

> If you need to add more information please [edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/327256/edit) your [question][answer] instead of adding a comment.

Comment: Many users come from discussion forums where it's common (and sometimes expected) to leave a new reply to add in more information. This gets confusing and isn't ideal.

Comment: A trick is to include [the edit link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/327256/edit) in the comment (so they don't have to locate "edit" on the page). Then they only need instructions on how to click on that link (I am ***not*** being sarcastic - they may be completely unfamiliar how things work here and still in 2019 it may be necessary to explain hyperlinks). The edit link may also work well for minimum effort users. (I don't know if an edit link will work or not in the Stack Exchange mobile applications.)

Comment: @Laurel  Yes looking at it, that's very similar.  I'd say I dislike the mockups in the other question but it's basically the same suggestion.